# What shell is SSMS 2012 based on and how can I darken the theme?

Tags: ide, themes, ssms, ssms-2012

I have a *dark* query editing environment, but the object explorer and other elements default to the white background. I really like `VS 2012` dark theme, and was hoping someone knew of a way to get `SSMS 2012` UI elements darker.

I've googled to no avail. There doesn't seem to be much documentation on SSMS and themes. I guess all `SQL` folks just like it plain and simple.

How do I darken the UI elements on SSMS 2012?

Answer (score 5):

`SSMS 2012` is based on `VS 2010`. There is an extension for `VS 2010` called *Color Themes Extension*, but SSMS does not have an *Extensions* menu item, so you have to copy the extension manually to `{$SqlServerPath}/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/Extensions`.

You can then install a theme called `Expression`, which is a *dark* theme based on Microsoft Expression product line and it works for SSMS, but unfortunately some controls like Object Explorer's background will stay white.

It's described in detail on [this blog](http://blog.bagearon.com/2012/03/sql-server-management-studio-2012-color-themes-extension-support/).

Comment: +1 good answer. Not against you, but I still think it's crap that only the editor gets affected by this. IMHO the extreme contrast between white and black is harder on my eyes than just using all white for the time being. I can't wait until they bring SSMS up to VS 2012 so we can have a *true* dark theme.

Comment: @Yuck: It's not just the editor, toolbars and other controls get dark also. But some controls have their background hardcoded to White, like the Object Explorer. Maybe you meant to comment on the answer below, that one will get you only darker colors in editor.

Comment: quite old, but should this work with SSMS 2012 in the Express version? Should any menu be added there?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get it working as explained in [Brad's blog](http://blog.bagearon.com/2012/03/sql-server-management-studio-2012-color-themes-extension-support/). So for those who couldn't neither;

- Create a new file with `.vssettings` extension (Like: SQLofObsidian.vssettings)
- Copy the entire `XML` [here](http://www.jimmcleod.net/files/SQL-of-Obsidian.vssettings.txt)
- Open the file you previously created with a text editor
- Paste the XML you previously copied and save the file
- Open SSMS 2012 and; Tools -> Import and Export -> Import selected evironment.. -> No, just.. -> Browse and select the `.vssettings` file

In the last step you can back up your current settings to roll back in case of an issue

Comment: The OP has asked how to _darken the UI elements_ specifically, not just the editor colors.